Disable Ktlint check on buil task
I have and KMP project with multiple modules. I have installed Ktlint and it works correctly. But I would like to disable it on build task.
What I've done so far was to try to disable it on my build.gradle.kts project file:
subprojects {
    ...

    plugins.withId("org.jlleitschuh.gradle.ktlint") {
        tasks.named("ktlintCheck").configure {
           enabled = false
        }
    }
}

How can I disable Ktlint only on build task?
